# Issue with promotional code activation form

Tags: javascript

I’m making a form on the site where the user can enter the promotional code and receive money for the balance of the site. But when i try to enter a promotional code (even send an empty promotional code, or input some digits), the page simply reloads, and the site’s console is empty. Although the page with entering the promotional code should not reload.

My JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.activate-voucher-btn', function () {
var el = $(this).parents('.bonus-code').find('.activate-voucher-input');
var code = el.val().trim();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/promocode',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {code: code},
        success: function (data) {
            toastr.info(data.status, data.message);
            updateBalance();
        },
        error: function (err) {
            toastr.error(err.status, err.message);
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

My blade code:

```
<div class="bonus-code"><div class="bonus-code-component"><form class="bonus-code-container f-2">
  <label class="bonus-code__warning mb-0">
    <span rv-translate="">Enter promo code</span>:
  </label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control text-uppercase activate-voucher-input" style="color: #000;">
  <button class="btn-link activate activate-voucher-btn" type="submit">Activate</button>
</form>
</div></div>
```

When i try to enter a promotional code, the page reloads (although it should not) and nothing happens. Where could the problem be?

Comment: _"the page reloads (although it should not)"_ Why shouldn't it? You're not doing anything to stop your form from being submitted. Seems like the easiest solution is to change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `<button>` element in a form's default behaviour is to submit the form.

There are two solutions to this. The first is to have your click event handler return false:

```
$(document).on('click', '.activate-voucher-btn', function() {
    // ... stuff
    return false;
});
```

The other is to use the `event` object's `preventDefault()` method:

```
$(document).on('click', '.activate-voucher-btn', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // ... stuff
});
```